# How to stop .click event from taking place dynamicly using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `$('.interaction').on('click', function(e){});` But in some case I don't want to allow the user to click on the element at all.

For some reason the user still able to click on the button and fire the event event though I did `.unbind()` event which did not work;

Basically if the condition `(activeState == 'R' || activeState == 'D')` is met, I don't want to allow the user to click on the following element `#hold,#resume,#mute,#unmute` otherwise I want to allow clicking them.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
$(function(){

    $('#test').click(function(){
        if(activeState == 'R' || activeState == 'D'){
            disableControlOps();
        } else {
            enableControlOps();
        }
    });


    function disableControlOps(){
        $('#hold,#resume,#mute,#unmute').addClass('icwsDisableButtons');


        $('#hold,#resume,#mute,#unmute').unbind( "click" );


    }

    function enableControlOps(){
        $('#hold,#resume,#mute,#unmute').removeClass('icwsDisableButtons');
    }


    //Handle interactions
    $('.interaction').on('click', function(e){

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.getJSON("index.php", function(data){
            console.log('Bingo!!!');
         });
    });

});
```

How do I stop the events from firing?

Comment: Have you tried to use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) for unbinding?

Comment: you can also disable the button. Just an idea!!

Comment: @Newinjava the button is an image and I handle the click using .click()

Comment: Or, you can also use pointer-events:none in the css rules

Comment: Can't you hide the controls... when it meets condition... Just an idea!

Comment: @Mike the .addClass method makes the image transparent. I don't really want to hide it rather make it looks disable and prevent clicks.

Comment: @EricMartinez `.off()` removed it all together I am no longer able to click on it at all.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` did you try this also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just return?

```
$('.interaction').on('click', function(e){
    if(activeState == 'R' || activeState == 'D') return;

    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $.getJSON("index.php", function(data){
        console.log('Bingo!!!');
     });
});
```

Comment: actually what I have done is this instead but using your idea    `if( $(this).hasClass('icwsDisableButtons') ){
    return;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 function disableControlOps(){
        $('#hold,#resume,#mute,#unmute').addClass('icwsDisableButtons');
        $('#hold,#resume,#mute,#unmute').css("Pointer-event","none" );

 }

 function enableControlOps(){
        $('#hold,#resume,#mute,#unmute').removeClass('icwsDisableButtons');
        $('#hold,#resume,#mute,#unmute').css("Pointer-event","auto" );
    }
```